# EF Lazy loading - can I retrieve child collection later?

Tags: entity-framework, lazy-loading

I use Code First with Entity Framework.

I have a class with virtual property to another class (lazy loading).

```
public class Order{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public virtual ICollection<OrderItem> OrderItems { get; set; }
}
```

If I get `Order` from database and do not include `OrderItem`, then close DbContext, is it possible to load them later? If yes, how?

eg.

```
private static Order GetFirstOrder(Func<Order, bool> predicate)
{
   using (var db = new MyContext())
   {
       return db.Orders.First(predicate);
   }
}

private static void DoSomething()
{
    var order = GetFirstOrder(a => a.Id == 1);
    //do something with OrderItems later?
}
```

Comment: If you want to load the related entities later you will obviously need the context instance. Create an instance, attach your entity so that the EntityChangeTracker can track it, and then lazy load the related entities.

Answer (score 1):

`Lazy loading` will be available *as long as the context of the query is alive*.

If it's closed, then it's over, you'll have to re-query (some `GetOrderItemsByOrder` query), or re-attach. Do something "manually", in any case.

Comment: 'as long as the context is alive' and the entity and wrapped by the `dynamic-proxy`.

Answer (score 0):

You should Include the collection name.

```
var myItemWithCollection = (from s in db.tableName.Include("ListName").Where(s => s.Id.Equals(ItemId)) select s).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: But if the method is already `return db.Orders.First(predicate);`, instead of `return db.Orders.Include("OrderItem").First(predicate);`, can it be loaded later? Or not?

Comment: Your problem is that the collection is null after the context is closed ? (and the rest of the fields are ok..)

Comment: It is null, and I understand why. But I want to know what I can do to load the collection later, after context is already disposed.

Comment: if you want to keep it in your member after the context is closed, you can do what I wrote.

Comment: @ilansch but this is eager loading, not lazy